# Extreme CPU usage from wireless mouse on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with high-end rig

Tags: wireless, mouse, 22.04, cpu

I noticed that my high-end PC running natively on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS had extremely high CPU usage for no reason. Upon research and investigation, I figured out it's my wireless mouse. With it turned off, CPU usage is ~0%, with it on, it's consistently at least 40% on all cores, with frequent spikes. Any tips? This mouse is a recent buy and I love it. Here are some relevant specs:

- Mouse: Razer Deathadder V2 Pro, connected via it's native 2.4 adapter
- CPU: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-12600KF × 16cores
- RAM: 32GB 3200MHz

Feel free to ask for any more info. All help is appreciated. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What messages do you see if you do `systemctl --system -f` and the plug in the mouse? Any warnings, errors? A flood of messages if you move the mouse, perhaps? If not, does lowering the DPI of the mouse help?

Comment: This is speculation, but I'm having a similar issue and it may be related to dpi and poll settings. Razer-cli allows you to adjust both of these settings